# How to import obj file without material

Tags: python, materials, scripting, import, obj

I have a script that repeatedly imports and deletes different .obj files.
[image]

But since the files are imported with standard empty material, a lot of garbage accumulates.

[image]

Is there a way to import files without assigning empty material to them?

I did not find something like: create_a_standard_material: True/False

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath="", filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl", use_edges=True, use_smooth_groups=True, use_split_objects=True, use_split_groups=False, use_groups_as_vgroups=False, use_image_search=True, split_mode='ON', global_clamp_size=0, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

Comment: I don't think any of the default Blender importers have such an option. I wish they did, though. For armatures too.

Comment: Just delete the material after you import?

Comment: My script imports and deletes several dozen objects in one pass. Imagine if there are several tens or hundreds of such useless materials and they are mixed with other, useful materials. It just takes inhuman patience to dig through this pile of rubbish. So manual removal is not an option. Of course, in the process of working on a project, you can add the materials I need to some list, but this is extra labor costs, and besides, you can easily get confused. Therefore, if there was a way to simply turn off the automatic creation of material, then this would save a lot of time and nerves.